# MaxScript: Detecting When An Object Is Deleted

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

How would I detect (or fire a function) if an object is deleted from the scene?

Answer (score 6):

Using [notifications](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MAXScript-Help/files/GUID-C1F6495F-5831-4FC8-A00C-667C5F2EAE36-htm.html)

```
fn nodeDeletedCallback =
(
  deletedObj = callbacks.notificationParam()
  print ("Deleting: " + (deletedObj as string))
)

Callbacks.addscript #nodePreDelete "nodeDeletedCallback()" id:#id_AStringYouCanUseLaterToIdentifyThisCallback
```

Comment: It says it is unable to convert result to string. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Also how would I check if an object is a box?

Comment: Compare with its class, for instance: classOf obj == Box. This returns true if the node stored in the obj variable is indeed a box, otherwise false.